# Custom Post Type Slug / Page Slug Conflict - Prevent use of reserved slug on page save?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, slug

I have a custom post type of portfolio (slug portfolio) in my theme and all is working well except one thing. When people create a page with a slug of portfolio, eg: example.com/portfolio, the theme thinks I'm wanting to use the custom post type archive page, not my page created in the editor.

Can I somehow "reserve" the slug portfolio when pages are saved to be sure it never gets used, maybe renamed to portfolio-page?

My project uses the methods outlined in this tutorial, here's the conflict I'm referring to:

> "Beyond having to patch the code there is one other catch here in that
>   you can’t call your Page slug the same thing as your custom post type
>   slug. Think of your custom post type slug as a reserved keyword;
>   however, you can make the title of your Page the same name as your
>   custom post type slug just as long as your Page slug is something
>   different." -
>   http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-post-type-pagination-chaining-method/

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: One option I see would be to remove this from the register_post_type() init:

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true ),

and just set 'rewrite' => false and just live with the ugly "single" portfolio items.

Comment: Vote up for your question as even I want to know the answer! I have worked with custom posts for a couple of times, but I never noticed this, and now after reading your question, I tried it. You're right, WordPress does get confused here!

Answer (score 14):

The following 2 filters allow you to hook into when WordPress checks the slug and are found in the function wp_unique_post_slug() in the wp-includes/post.php file.

There are 2 filters, one for hierarchical posts and one for non-hierarchical. The hierarchical filter provides the ID for the post parent so if the $post_parent is 0, you know this is a "base" post.

The filters also pass the $post_type if you wanted to add specific post types to your logic.

By returning "true", you're telling WordPress that this slug is bad so WordPress adds on a suffix, just like it would do if you were trying to us a post name/slug that is already taken.

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', 'portfolio_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', 10, 4 );
function portfolio_is_bad_hierarchical_slug( $is_bad_hierarchical_slug, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent ) {
    if ( !$post_parent && $slug == 'portfolio' )
        return true;
    return $is_bad_hierarchical_slug;
}

add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', 'portfolio_is_bad_flat_slug', 10, 3 );
function portfolio_is_bad_flat_slug( $is_bad_flat_slug, $slug, $post_type ) {
    if ( $slug == 'portfolio' )
        return true;
    return $is_bad_flat_slug;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am still facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Create a page with a slug of 'portfolio' and make it 'Private'. It will be hidden from public when reserving the slug from futher usage.

Answer (score 1):

Came across exactly this problem when investigating a pagination problem. We have a News homepage (slug "news") and pagination was failing ... attempts to get to /news/page/2/ always resulted in '404 - Not Found'.

The problem turned out to be that our News custom type had also been given the slug "news". By changing the latter (for example to "news_archive") the problem was fixed. This left the original news URL references unchanged. Changing the News homepage slug also worked but then all URLS would incorporate the changed slug.