# Prevent page slug from interfering with custom post type archive permalink?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

In my plugin, I'm creating a custom post type that has an archive and uses the rewrite parameter to choose a slug:

```
$args = array (
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'lessons', 'with_front' => false)
);
register_post_type ('my_plugin_lesson', $args);
```

With this code, I get an archive of the 'my_plugin_lesson' posts at `example.com/lessons/`.

However, I can also create a Page with the title "Lessons", and WordPress will assign it the slug 'lessons'.  The View Page link on the admin panel for this page will be `example.com/lessons/`, but the page is inaccessible because WordPress shows the archive for my custom post type.

Is there a way to prevent WordPress from choosing a slug for pages or posts that interfere with the slug of my custom post types?

Comment: Take a look at @Rachel Carden's answer to this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45152/22534

Comment: @ialocin Thanks!  I guess this is a duplicate.  I don't know why I couldn't find that before.

Comment: @G.M. Agreed.  Sorry.  I've already tried deleting it, but it won't let me delete either.

Comment: I think your apologies is not needed in this case ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you already find the solution, because you figured out this question was already asked and answered...

However, once this question is a bounty one and cannot be closed as duplicate, I want to make sense to this, and add (a bit of) additional value on the answers already posted.

What is done in those answers (the [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45152/22534) by **@RachelCarden** and the one posted here by **@matthew-boynes**) is what you need, but it is *hardcoded*, i.e. you have to *manually* add the cpt archive slug in the filter function.

What I want to obtain is a filter that works in the same way, but *dinamically*, something like:

```
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', 'prevent_slug_override', 99, 3);
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', 'prevent_slug_override', 99, 3);

function prevent_slug_override( $now, $slug, $type ) {
  if ( in_array($type, array('nav_menu_item', 'revision', 'attachment') ) )
    return $now;
  $cpts = get_post_types( array('_builtin' => false), 'objects' );
  $check_bad = array();
  foreach ( $cpts as $cpt => $object ) {
    if ( $object->has_archive ) {
      if (
        ! empty($object->rewrite) && isset($object->rewrite['slug']) &&
        ! empty($object->rewrite['slug']) && ($object->rewrite['slug'] != $cpt)
      ) {
        $check_bad[] = $object->rewrite['slug'];
      } else {
        $check_bad[] = is_string($object->has_archive) ? $object->has_archive : $cpt;
      }
    }
  }
  if ( in_array($slug, $check_bad) ) return true;
  return $now;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered submitting a core patch for this?  Shouldn't WordPress avoid assigning a slug to a post if it is already in use by a custom post type?

Comment: @BenMiller before submit a core patch it should be tested because there are a lot of configuration possibilities: taking into account configuration in permalink settings and options for `register_post_type` there are many scenario to consider. Also note that if some custom rewrite rule exists, more variables are added to the problem. Maybe if I have time...

Comment: Nice, I like it and will use it in the future - for sure! @BenMiller Good thing you couldn't delete the question :) This is absolutely bounty worthy!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could leverage the filters in `wp_unique_post_slug` to prevent this conflict. Try the following

```
function wpse_109072_is_slug_conflict( $false, $slug, $post_type ) {
    return ( 'page' == $post_type && 'lessons' == $slug );
}
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', 'wpse_109072_is_slug_conflict', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', 'wpse_109072_is_slug_conflict', 10, 3 );
```