# Can I change the slug of my archive page on a Custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT with a slug that is the same of a page. This has been done on purpose as I hope I was able to control the slug of my archive page to be something like

```
http://www.test.me/page
http://www.test.me/page/archive.php
```

So page is the name of my personal page template, but also the cpt slug.

Looking around for a solution I found somebody that was suggesting to add the with_front option. I didn't find that many bits so I am still confused on what it does.

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'page', 'with_front' => true )
```

I then also find this answer here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45152/26216 - with a couple of custom function which is even more confusing.

Can somebody give me an hint?
Thanks